# query for a range of records in result

Tags: t-sql

I am wondering if there is some easy way, a function, or other method to return data from a query with the following results.

I have a SQL Express DB 2008 R2, a table that contains numerical data in a given column, say col T.

I am given a value X in code and would like to return up to three records. The record where col T equals my value X, and the record before and after, and nothing else. The sort is done on col T. The record before may be beginning of file and therefore not exist, likewise, if X equals the last record then the record after would be non existent, end of file/table.

The value of X may not exist in the table.

This I think is similar to get a range of results in numerical order.

Any help or direction in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again,

Comment: What do "before" and "after" mean?  Without an `ORDER BY` specified there is no valid expectation of order.

Comment: In the post I indicated that the sort is on col T. So before and after are referring to the record immediately before and the record immediately following the potential record that matches X, though there may not be an exact match as indicated.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because you specify SQL 2008, but if you upgrade to sql 2012, you can utilize the lag() and lead() functions to get values from the previous or next records in the set.

Comment: Sounds like an awsome new feature of SQL 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be the most optimal solution, but:

```
SELECT T
FROM theTable
WHERE T = X
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T
    FROM theTable
    WHERE T > X
    ORDER BY T
) blah
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T
    FROM theTable
    WHERE T < X
    ORDER BY T DESC
) blah2
```

Comment: I'll test this and see how it works. The table will be quite large so I will be concerned about speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @x int = 100

;WITH t as 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T ASC) AS row_nm,*
    from YourTable
)
, t1 as
(
    select *
    from t
    WHERE T = @x
)
select *
from t 
CROSS APPLY t1
WHERE t.row_nm BETWEEN t1.row_nm -1 and t1.row_nm + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll test this and see how it works. The table will be quite large so I will be concerned about speed.