# How to SELECT rows surrounding a row not by id

Tags: mysql, select, join

There are a lot of questions here regarding selecting surrounding rows of a matched row that use ID to do the trick. That's not what I need, as my table is words and I need to get words ordered by words.

Example Table: Word

```
id    word
1     boing
2     aleluya
3     chimp
4     dinner
5     after
6     zup
7     pop
8     house
9     chain
```

Let's say I would like the 3 surrounding rows of "dinner" ordered by word ASC, my results should be:

```
id    word
1     boing
9     chain
3     chimp
4     dinner
8     house
7     pop
6     zup
```

What query do I need to use? I tried  this:

```
SELECT word FROM `word` t WHERE t.word <> 'dinner' 
ORDER BY abs( t.word - (SELECT t2.word  FROM word t2 WHERE t2.word = 'dinner'))
LIMIT 5
```

which is obviously not working.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264868/query-for-a-range-of-records-in-result/12264966#12264966 You should be able to extrapolate for 3 rows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.word FROM word t 
WHERE t.word >= 
(
    SELECT lo.word FROM `word` lo 
    WHERE lo.word <= 'dinner' ORDER BY lo.word DESC LIMIT 3,1
)
ORDER BY t.word ASC LIMIT 0,7
;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c6bf/16/0)

Comment: This query runs much faster than the one from Daniel +1

Comment: This query won't work as expected when the column has duplicated entries.

Comment: If necessary, adding `DISTINCT` to both the outer and inner `SELECT` statements will suppress duplicates

Comment: this works great until the word you need to get the surrounding rows from is at the beginning of the list. For example, replace the word 'dinner' in the above code with 'after'. That word is the first in the list and so the code returns nothing. How can we handle the entries at the beginnings?

Answer (score 2):

Try deriving a RANK for the ordered column set. Something like this will work:

```
SELECT 
   e.id, e.word 
FROM  
   (select id, word, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS RANK from Word, (select @rownum := 0) r order by word asc) d, -- for getting the rank for 'dinner'
   (select id, word, @num:=@num+1 AS RANK from Word, (select @num := 0) r order by word asc) e -- for getting the rank for the other words
WHERE 
   d.word='dinner' AND 
   e.RANK BETWEEN d.RANK-3 AND d.RANK+3 -- +/- 3 columns;
```

Hope this helps!